# How do I proceed on populating the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got these item properties and I need to populate the UI by setting the name on each UITableViewCell, each cell has the following properties:

- Name
- Description
- Photo
- Old Price
- New Price

However, I don't know how I should proceed. Could you guys take a look and give me a hand, please?

***Printed Item names:***

- HTML e CSS
- Sistema de Banco de Dados
- Programação com Arduino
- Segredos do Hacker Ético
- Google Android
- Android Essencial
- Desenvolvimento de Jogos Para Android
- iOS: Programe para iPhone e iPad
- A Guerra dos tronos
- Crepusculo

***ViewController:***

```
import UIKit

class TelaCategorias: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    //Class Instanciated
    var item:[CategoriaIDItems]?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for item in item!{

        print(item.nome)

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (item?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableIDCategorias", for: indexPath) as! TelaCategoriasCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = ?????


        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is waaaaay too broad and too vague for this cite, but since you're new I posted an answer that should help you get started.

Comment: "cite" should have been "site".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Append the item names to an array
- In cellForRowAt indexPath:

  ```
  cell.textLabel.text = yourArrayName[indexPath.row]
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much dude! It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

So you need to read up on setting up a data source for a table view.

Before you tackle YOUR table view, you might want to go through a Swift/iOS tutorial on table views and follow that so you get the gist of it.

Suggestion: Don't use the name "item" (singular) for your array. Use the name "items" plural. An item is a thing. Items is more than one thing.

Now define a struct that has fields for the properties that you want to display in your table view.

Make `items` be an array of those structs.

Write your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method so it fetches an item from the items array and uses that item to set the fields in your table view cell.

If you don't understand any of these steps you will need to do some study and read up on how  to do this. Expect it to take a couple of days to sort this out. It's confusing the first time you tackle it, but you need to go through the exercise.

Comment: Hello Duncan! Man, thank you so much for the whole explanation, I really appreciate it, I got to fix the app now it's working perfectly. Would you recommend me any good tutorial?